# Windows 10 mysterious memory usage

Tags: windows-10, memory

I'm having this issue for some time already. I tried formatting to eliminate any chance that a malware is sucking the memory and that didn't help. Normally (or at least when I first bought this laptop Lenovo Y50-70) the memory usage wouldn't go over 5%, I have 16GB of RAM. Checking the resource manager, the sum of all processes' memory wouldn't really come up to a 20% of the 16GB. I also don't think that there is a memory leak cause by an outdated driver. Neither are there some files locked in the memory.

Any ideas what may be causing this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: My windows 10 machine uses about that much memory at any given moment when idling. I don't think you have a problem. It looks like you have 16gb of RAM to begin with so you have plenty to spare still. Memory is only good if it's being used right?

Comment: The problem isn't when the machine is idle. I just tried to close all the applications (which I normally have open all the time) to check what is using the memory. The extra 10%-15% are needed on regular usage which consists of more applications (Slack, Coding IDEs, Skype, MS Office), multiple servers (Database, Web, Index) and many chrome tabs.

Comment: so is your issue with the 3.2GB in use, and you think that is too much?

Comment: you have to look at processes and see which processes use RAM. but you use Chrome, this is a known program that has a heavy RAM usage

Comment: @FrankThomasit yes that is the issue. It is not about what I think. Looking at the processes' total memory usage it is far from 3.2GB. Is this normal?

Comment: again ,post a picture of the process tab from RAMMAp

Comment: while chrome is off
http://i.imgur.com/a80wnIY.png

Comment: now I also need the other views to see the overall memory usage. Run a cmd.exe as admin and run this **wpr.exe -start ReferenceSet && timeout 30 && wpr.exe -start C:\MemoryUsage.etl**. Zip the ETL and share (Onedrive share link) it.

Comment: I'm getting this error `The Logging Mode does not match with the profile passed.`

Comment: try this: **wpr.exe -start ReferenceSet -fileMode && timeout 30 && wpr.exe -start C:\MemoryUsage.etl**. I forgot the **-fileMode** flag

Comment: I think you meant **wpr.exe -start ReferenceSet -fileMode && timeout 30 && wpr.exe -stop C:\MemoryUsage.etl** 
here is the ETL file. I compressed it, as it is 280MB. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7m5FzvzdLxBUVJSdmg2VVRDZHM

Comment: it seams to be the sum of lots of running programs (some JAVA related, PostGres). I heard from an user that the Intel HD driver leaks memory if you see a too large RAM size in BIOS/UEFI. maybe this applies to your HD4600, too. I see that the dwm has 100MB modified memory and so here the memory compression kicks up and compresses it. so check for updated drivers for the 4600 and 860M

Comment: Keep in mind though, a memory leak will keep accumulating memory under the leaky process, it won't just disappear from the system free, and from the process that had claimed it. Memory leaks occur in the program Heap, so the unreleased memory is still within the processes memory footprint, and as such are reclaimed when the process exits.

Comment: do newer GPU drivers improve the memory usage?